# Query Working, but unable to echo after running

Tags: php, mysql

```
function supervisor_from_email($email, $p_id) {
    $email = sanitize($email);
    return mysql_query("SELECT pm.supervisor FROM project_members AS pm JOIN users AS u ON pm.project_member_id = u.user_id WHERE u.email = $email AND pm.project_id = $p_id");
}
```

is the function I call, $email and $p_id are correct and I have run the query on the database and it returns the correct value(which is either a 1 or 0)

I want to be able to echo this on the page and then decide whether a checkbox will be checked or not depending on it however when I try and echo after running the function like so:

```
$supervisor = supervisor_from_email($email, $p_id);
echo $supervisor;
```

It does not work? Any ideas?

Comment: Check out what [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/mysql_query) returns.  It doesn't return a string.  You need to use [`mysql_fetch_row`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_row) (or similar) to get the value.

Comment: $email is a string so it needs to be quoted in the query. It would be better anyway to use PDO + binding as mysql_ functions are deprecated

Comment: the query returns 1 row which has a value of 1 or 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT pm.supervisor FROM project_members AS pm JOIN users AS u ON pm.project_member_id = u.user_id WHERE u.email = '$email' AND pm.project_id = $p_id");
if (!$result) 
{
die(mysql_error()); 
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row['supervisor'];
}
```

OR

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT pm.supervisor FROM project_members AS pm JOIN users AS u ON pm.project_member_id = u.user_id WHERE u.email = '$email' AND pm.project_id = $p_id");
if (!$result) 
{
die(mysql_error()); 
}
mysql_result($result,0);
```

Comment: With this i get the error:  mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear, the only value being returned is a 1 or a 0, not an array, I only want supervisor which is 1 or 0

Comment: Then try replacing $row['email] with $row['supervisor']; and tell me what happens :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28395/discussion-between-user2286553-and-imane-fateh)

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_query` return a resource so you must fetch this resource to get the data binded into this resource by using `mysql_fetch_array` and after that you must go to the new `mysqli` library because the old `mysql` library will deprecated soon :)

**Try this :**

```
function supervisor_from_email($email, $p_id)
    {
        $email = sanitize($email);
        $email_rs = mysql_query("SELECT pm.supervisor FROM project_members AS pm JOIN users AS u ON pm.project_member_id = u.user_id WHERE u.email = '$email' AND pm.project_id = $p_id");
        if(is_resource($email_rs))
            {
                $email_res = mysql_fetch_array($email_rs);
                $email = $email_res[0];
                return $email;
            }
        else
            return "Invalid supervisor";
    }
```

Tell me the result :)

Comment: @user2286553 : This error mean that no resource has been returned from your query so your query has an error within i think if your try to echo the query before executing it and tell me the result so i can get exactly the error place but as i think you need to qoute string values inside your query :)

Comment: @user2286553 : Then when you want to use the mysql_query function and stop code when their where any error in the query always use it as this : mysql_query($yourquery)or die(mysql_error());

Comment: @user2286553 Please answer me if my infos was useful and if that solve your problem and if you need additional explaining i am here :)

Comment: Hi i have echo'd the query it returns:  Resource id #17

Answer (score 1):

Your function should be like this..

```
function supervisor_from_email($email, $p_id) {
    $email = sanitize($email);
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT pm.supervisor FROM project_members AS pm JOIN users AS u ON pm.project_member_id = u.user_id WHERE u.email = $email AND pm.project_id = $p_id");
   $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $row['supervisor'];

}
```

it will return array with value try this

Comment: with this, I get the error mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: @user2286553 what will be the result of your query is that only one record

Comment: @user2286553 first echo the query and then see what it shows there my be error in query